# Procfile declared none

Tags: heroku

I am trying to deploy to Heroku. I keep getting an application error.
I created a `ProcFile` file without any extension, but Heroku doesn't seem to recognize it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: check what you have in logs - either with cli (heroku logs --tail) or in heroku web interface https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs-with-the-heroku-dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the `ProcFile` file to `Procfile` and there was more than one `requirements.txt` file It has been erased and create one `requirements.txt` file for all downloaded

Comment: The problem you asked about would have been solved by the answer I gave, which is the first half of the question you repeated here. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Accepting that answer by clicking on the ✔ would be more appropriate than adding your own that just says the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the file doesn't have an extension, but it needs to be called `Procfile`, *exactly*. Your file is called `ProcFile` with a capital `F`.

Rename it to `Procfile`, commit, and redeploy.